# How to calculate a column based of rules applied in others columns in pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, jupyter

```
person     health    life    power    nexy    prox
mike       40         50     45       20      40
Anton      20         30     10       50      40
```

I want to create a column `four_of_five` that return `yes` if there's a value greater than 40 in at least 4 of these 5 columns: `health, life, power, nexy, prox`

```
  person     health      life    power    nexy    prox    four_of_five
    mike       40         50      45       20      40        yes
    Anton      20         30      10       50      40        no
```

mike return **yes** because he has values equal or greater than 40 in 4 out of 5 columns
Anton return **no** because he has values equal or greater than 40 in only 2 out of 5 columns

I want to solve this without using a lot of `if's and or's`.  Is there an easy way to do it?

Comment: i think you meant 40 and not 4, I edited the question. check and advise if you don't agree

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is one way to do it without if

```
df['four_of_five']=(
    ((df.iloc[:,1:]>=40) # True/False where value meets or exceeds 40
     .sum(axis=1)>=4) # count across the row and check if its equal or exceeds 4
    .map({True: 'Yes', False:'No'})) # map True/False to Yes, No
df
```

```
    person  health  life    power   nexy    prox    four_of_five
0   mike        40    50       45     20      40    Yes
1   Anton       20    30       10     50      40    No
```